# "sh: missing ]" terminal output error when I run docker-compose run composer

Tags: docker-compose, containers, composer-php

I keep getting this error "sh: missing ]" when I run this command on my terminal: docker-compose run composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel .

Below is my docker compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
  server:
    image: 'nginx:stable-alpine'
    ports: 
      - '8000:80'
    volumes: 
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on: 
      - php
      - mysql
  php:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    volumes: 
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    env_file: 
      - ./env/mysql.env
  composer:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: composer.dockerfile
    volumes: 
      - ./src:/var/www/html
```

I think I am missing something but it will be great if anyone points me to the error either in my file or there is something I am missing out.

I was expecting composer to be successfully installed in my container.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have been able to resolve the issue. It had to force my docker-compose to rebuild my dockerfile by adding the --build command and everything worked.